Intellij : Failed to remote VM , Failed to connect session
I'm using Intellij, and I cannot connect WebSocket Server. In console falied to remote VM and falied to connect session. How could I connect WebSocket server?
errors:
2024-11-27T01:53:13.664+09:00 DEBUG 9340 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.m.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession     : Failed to connect session id=61818f8d-d731-ac9f-3034-d028855e44ed

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [ws://localhost:8080/portfolio] failed
Caused by: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [ws://localhost:8080/portfolio] failed
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:429) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.31.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.31.jar:10.1.31]

and application.yml:
websocket:
  server:
    url: ws://localhost:8080/portfolio

My Codes
Configs
package study.withkbo.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import study.withkbo.game.web.CustomInterceptor;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final CustomInterceptor customInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(customInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/api/gameInfo/{month}");
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}

package study.withkbo.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import study.withkbo.server.service.ChatWebSocketHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private final ChatWebSocketHandler chatWebSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(chatWebSocketHandler, "/portfolio");
        System.out.println("Registered WebSocket Handler, WebSocketConfig");
    }
}

package study.withkbo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio") 
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue"); 
    }

}

ClientService Code for connect Server
package study.withkbo.client.service;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import study.withkbo.client.handler.MyStompSessionHandler;
import study.withkbo.server.service.ChatWebSocketHandler;

@Service
public class ClientService {
    private WebSocketStompClient stompClient;
    @Value("${websocket.server.url}")
    private String serverUrl;
    private final ChatWebSocketHandler chatWebSocketHandler;

    public ClientService(ChatWebSocketHandler chatWebSocketHandler) {
        this.chatWebSocketHandler = chatWebSocketHandler;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("serverUrl: " + serverUrl);
        WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());

        connect();
    }
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to WebSocket server at: " + serverUrl);
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler(chatWebSocketHandler);
        stompClient.connect(serverUrl, sessionHandler);
    }
}

And Handlers that failed:
package study.withkbo.client.handler;

import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import study.withkbo.server.service.ChatWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    private final ChatWebSocketHandler chatWebSocketHandler;

    public MyStompSessionHandler(ChatWebSocketHandler chatWebSocketHandler) {
        this.chatWebSocketHandler = chatWebSocketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        System.out.println("STOMP session connected: " + session.getSessionId());
        WebSocketSession webSocketSession = chatWebSocketHandler.getSession(session.getSessionId());
        if (webSocketSession != null) {
            System.out.println("WebSocketSession URI: " + webSocketSession.getUri());
            try {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage("STOMP connect to WebSocket"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        session.send("/app/recruit/{roomName}", "Hello, Server!");
        session.subscribe("/topic/{roomName}", new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return String.class; 
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                System.out.println("get message : " + payload);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        System.err.println("Transport Error: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        System.err.println("STOMP connection failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}

package study.withkbo.server.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Component
public class ChatWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, WebSocketSession> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        // Log when the WebSocket connection is established
        System.out.println("WebSocket connected: " + session.getId() + " | URI: " + session.getUri());
        sessions.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("handleTextMessage: " + session.getId() + sessions);
        System.out.println("handleTextMessage: " + message.getPayload());

        sessions.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println("key : "+ key + " value : " + value);
            if(!key.equals(session.getId())){ 
                try {
                    value.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        sessions.remove(session.getId());
        System.out.println("afterConnectionClosed: " + session.getId() + "| CloseStatus : " + status);
    }

    public WebSocketSession getSession(String sessionId) {
        return sessions.get(sessionId);
    }
}

